# lifting function into IO monad to parse a json string read from a file

Tags: haskell

I am having the problem that `readFile` returns an `IO String` but parse expects a regular `String` (or in the example below a `ByteString`). I though I simply use `liftM` but the example below still fails. What is the problem?

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Attoparsec
import Data.ByteString (ByteString, pack)
import Data.Maybe
import Network.HTTP
import Network.URI
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import Control.Monad

main = do
    myres  <-  liftM parse json (C.readFile "dummy.json")
    print myres
```

ERROR:

```
Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> Parser a0'
            with actual type `Parser Value'
In the second argument of `liftM', namely `json'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  myres <- liftM parse json (C.readFile "dummy.json")
In the expression:
  do { myres <- liftM parse json (C.readFile "dummy.json");
       print myres }
```

Comment: For readability I recommend instead doing `import Control.Applicative` and using `myres <- parse json <$> c.readFile "dummy.json"`.

Comment: `main = parse json <$> C.readFile "dummy.json" >>= print` is yet better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss parentheses around `(parse json)`, so `liftM` is applied to `parse`